# How to wipe sd card in rooted android lollipop?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

how to wipe sd card permanently in android rooted lolliop.I have used this link (
stackoverflow.com/questions/13737327/android-wipe-out-sd-card-programatically), but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Wiping a flash card is [not so simple](http://blog.erratasec.com/2011/02/whats-deal-with-deleting-data-from.html) even if you have full access.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void wipingSdcard() {
    File deleteMatchingFile = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
    try {
        File[] filenames = deleteMatchingFile.listFiles();
        if (filenames != null && filenames.length > 0) {
            for (File tempFile : filenames) {
                if (tempFile.isDirectory()) {
                    wipeDirectory(tempFile.toString());
                    tempFile.delete();
                } else {
                    tempFile.delete();
                }
            }
        } else {
            deleteMatchingFile.delete();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void wipeDirectory(String name) {
    File directoryFile = new File(name);
    File[] filenames = directoryFile.listFiles();
    if (filenames != null && filenames.length > 0) {
        for (File tempFile : filenames) {
            if (tempFile.isDirectory()) {
                wipeDirectory(tempFile.toString());
                tempFile.delete();
            } else {
                tempFile.delete();
            }
        }
    } else {
        directoryFile.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it say, and what device are you trying on?

Comment: and doesn't do anything

Comment: Is there any way using "android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE"

Answer (score 0):

ExternalStorageFormatter class takes care of formatting storage devices. But it is not exposed to 3P apps.

http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/os/storage/ExternalStorageFormatter.java

Go through the methods in that class and see if you can use any reflection techniques to trigger formatting from that class.

Comment: Does it works properly on Android 5x ?
I will try to take methods from the class .

Comment: It should. You can see here how it's being invoked from the Settings page: http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/MediaFormat.java

Comment: how to fix error related to 'import android.os.storage.IMountService' in the class ?